# How do I cluster data according to Hamming distance

Tags: clustering, python, binary-data

I've a list of binary strings and I'd like to cluster them in Python, using Hamming distance as metric. I also would like to set the number of centroids (i.e. clusters) to create.

Which algorithm do you suggest?

Comment: you can use k-nearestneighbours, with metric as the hamming distance. a simple google search yielded this result, 
 https://www.saedsayad.com/k_nearest_neighbors.htm

Comment: Yeah, there are lot of algorithms. The problem is if their Python implementation works correctly on strings, hence the question.

Comment: Not an answer to the question but I would opt for a Bernoulli Mixture model in this case.

Comment: @JosyulaKrishna k nearest neighbors is not a *clustering* algorithm.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse thanks for the correction, you are right. apologies.

Answer (score 2):

The obvious first thing to try is hierarchical clustering.

Because it can use an arbitrary distance matrix.

Why don't *you* just try some? That's faster than asking on a web site...

Comment: Indeed I've tried some, like Affinity propagation - in which I can't (don't know how to ) set a fixed number of centroids - or k-medoids (which actually works).
Now I've asked here in order to find more solutions.
Agglomerative Clustering is a hierarchical clustering algorithm supplied by scikit, but I don't know how to give strings as input, since it accepts couple (x,y) as elements, if I'm not wrong.

Comment: You *can* also give a distance matrix, as you probably did for affinity propagation. See the documentation.